# PowerShell equivalent of LINQ SelectMany method

Tags: linq, powershell

I'm writing PowerShell code to get all the local IPv4 addresses, excluding the loopback one. I need something like the LINQ SelectMany method, but I can't figure out how to do this with PS filters. This is the code I have so far, which works using a plain old ArrayList:

```
function Get-Computer-IP-Address()
{
    $ipAddresses = New-Object System.Collections.ArrayList

    $networkAdaptersWithIp = Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | ? { $_.IPAddress -ne $null }
    foreach ($networkAdapter in $networkAdaptersWithIp)
    {
        foreach ($ipAddress in $networkAdapter.IPAddress)
        {
            if ($ipAddress -notlike "127.*" -and $ipAddress -notlike "*::*")
            {
                $ipAddresses.Add($ipAddress)
            }
        }
    }

    if ($ipAddresses.Length -eq 0)
    {
        throw "Failed to find any non-loopback IPv4 addresses"
    }

    return $ipAddresses
}
```

I'd like to know if there's a cleaner way to do it, with less code.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You can do it if you combine `Foreach-Object` and `Where-Object` like this:

```
$ipaddresses = @(
  Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | 
  ? { $_.IPAddress -ne $null } |
  % { $_.IPAddress } |
  ? { $_ -notlike "127.*" -and $_ -notlike "*::*" })
```

Note the `@(...)`. This causes that if result of the pipeline inside is *nothing*, empty array is assigned to `$ipaddresses`.

Comment: Excellent, that works, thank you! So "%" is the trick I need. Thanks for explaining the @ as well.

Comment: ? = where-object;   % = foreach-object;

Answer (score 33):

Just to answer the question from the subject 
**"PowerShell equivalent of LINQ SelectMany method"**:

```
collection.SelectMany(el => el.GetChildren()) // SelectMany in C#
```

is equivalent to

```
$collection | % { $_ }                    # SelectMany in PowerShell for array of arrays
$collection | % { $_.GetChildren() }      # SelectMany in PowerShell for complex object
```

Example

```
$a = (1,2,3),('X','F'),'u','y'
$a.Length                # output is 4
($a | % { $_ }).Length   # output is 7
```

Another example

```
$dirs = dir -dir c:
$childFiles = $dirs | % { $_.GetFiles() }
$dirs.Length          # output is 6
$childFiles.Length    # output is 119
```

Answer (score 12):

I would also mention that the PowerShell equivalent of SelectMany is `Select-Object -ExpandProperty <property name of a collection>`.  However this doesn't work very well with this example because the property `IPAddress` is an array of string.  Flattening that array of string products individual strings with other properties attached e.g.:

```
Get-WmiObject Win32_NetworkAdapterConfiguration | Where {$_.IPAddress} | 
    Select Description -Expand IPAddress
```

Unfortunately, PowerShell treats `System.String` objects specially and as a result it doesn't want to display anything except the string's value (IPAddress in this case).  Getting it to also display the other properties (Description in this example) is not practical (possible?) AFAICT.